# Netlogo: Color turtles who share a parameter to the same color

Tags: netlogo

Is there a good way to set the color of turtles that share the same parameter to the same color?  I can't think of the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

By "share the same paramter", I assume you mean "have the same value of an attribute.  Use `with`.  E.g., `ask turtles with [size = 2] [set color blue]`

**Edit:**

If you have man different possible attribute values, the same idea holds, but you will probably want to use `scale-color`.  E.g., `ask turtles [set color scale-color blue size 0 5000]`

Comment: close...

Correct, by "share the same parameter" I do mean "have the same value of an attribute."  However lets assume there are over a 5000 possible values.

Comment: Hmmm, that worked pretty well.  Is there a way to add more colors than just one (blue)?

What I really need is a way to assign a color to turtles that share the same attribute value, but I can't do it manually as I will have too many values to just do ask turtles with [size = 2], ask turtles with [size = 3], etc etc.

Comment: @user3637405 The is already an answer to your question as asked.  If you want to try again with a new question, do so.  But you will need to be much more specific about how you want the turtles colored.  At the most general level, you can simply write a `color-turtles` function that implements any rule you wish to follow.